# how to navigate view from ouside response function using NavigationView in swiftui?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am using NavigationView to navigate from one view to another view. On button action I want to navigate another page. I have used multiple network calling to check & navigate another page.

I have two function in view. One is **doLogin**. If I  **isActiveWelcomeView = true** in doLogin method, it navigate to WelcomeView. It is working fine. But when I use  isActiveWelcomeView = true in **onResponse** function, it is not navigate to WelcomeView. onResponse is protocol funciton which I implemented FundTransferDashboard view & server data come to **onResponse** function. I have to check all verification on this function & then navigate to another page.

Here is the sample code..

```
struct FundTransferDashboard: View ,LoginProtocol{
                
                @State private var isActiveWelcomeView = false
                
                
                var body: some View {
                    
                    ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                        
                        
                        NavigationView {
                            VStack {
                                
                                Button(action: {
                                    
                                    doLogin()
                                    
                                }) {
                                    HStack {
                                        
                                        Image("lock")
                                            .resizable()
                                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .leading)
                                            .padding(10)
                                        
                                        
                                        Text("LOGIN")
                                            .padding(.leading, 40)
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                            .font(.system(size: 25, weight: Font.Weight.bold))
                                            .padding(10)
                                        
                                        Spacer()
                                    }
                                    Spacer()
                                } .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                
                                
                                NavigationLink("", destination:  WelcomeView(), isActive: $isActiveWelcomeView)
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                func doLogin(){
                    //calling  network
                }
                func onResponse(loginResponse: LoginResponseModel){
                   //reponse....
                isActiveWelcomeView = true
                }
            }
```

Here is the protocol

```
    protocol LoginProtocol {
      func onResponse(loginResponse:LoginResponseModel)
   }
```

I have use @State to navigate from one view to anotherview. What is the wrong with code? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Your code, as written, seems to work fine. But, it wouldn't surprise me if you're getting a side effect of doing asynchronous work in your `doLogin` method that is effecting the outcome. Generally, you should not do async work in a `View` and instead move it to an `ObservableObject`. For example:

```
protocol LoginProtocol {
    func onResponse(loginResponse:LoginResponseModel)
}

class FundTransferDashboardViewModel : ObservableObject, LoginProtocol {
    @Published var isActiveWelcomeView = false
    
    func doLogin(){
        //mock an async call
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.onResponse(loginResponse: LoginResponseModel())
        }
    }
    func onResponse(loginResponse: LoginResponseModel){
        //reponse....
        isActiveWelcomeView = true
    }
}

struct FundTransferDashboard: View{
    @StateObject private var viewModel = FundTransferDashboardViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        viewModel.doLogin()
                    }) {
                        Text("Login")
                    }
                    NavigationLink("", destination:  Text("Welcome"), isActive: $viewModel.isActiveWelcomeView)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Enamul Did this answer your question?